# nodejs, redis and mailparser wont parse an email

Tags: email, node.js, email-parsing

I am using mailparser by andris(https://github.com/andris9/mailparser). I am sending an email via redis to an nodejs app. The mailparser for somereason is unable to parse it. What could be causing the issue?

The code to get the email from redis. `client` is an instance of node_redis Client. MailParser is andris' mailparser. The email in redis is sent via another server, to whose channel i have subscribed. The email sent, when saved in a text file and parsed using andris' test.js, gives the expected output.

```
client.subscribe('email1');

client.on('message', function(channel, message){
    var Parser = new MailParser();
    Parser.on('headers', function(headers){
        console.log(headers.addressesTo[0].address);
    });
    Parser.feed(message);
    Parser.end();
});
```

I found the reason for this. The input I saw receiving had \r\n converted to \n

Comment: Need more information, code, error message, anything.

Comment: I added the code and a few more details.

Comment: @Amit Do you find the solution?

Comment: @ZuzooVn As mentioned, The input was receiving \r\n instead of \n, and hence the mail parser failed to parse

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
 Parser.feed(message);
```

I believe you want

```
Parser.write(message);
```

I couldn't find the *feed* method in the documentation. I am using the *write* function and it's working. The message is the original unaltered email message, including headers, body, and attachments.